# Select all matching results from selectize function keyword search

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I have a list of data rows where I am using selectize function to view them on a shiny application. multiple select is set to true. When I type in the keywords it shows the matching results, but I am unable to select all the matching results in a single click. i have to manually select all the possible matching results one by one. Is there any way I can select all of them in a single click? As an example, if i type "ala" in the text bar, i should be able to select "Alabama" and "Alaska" in a single click:

[image]

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Selectize examples',
      selectizeInput('e2', '2. Multi-select', choices = state.name, multiple = TRUE
      )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ex_out <- renderPrint({
    str(sapply(sprintf('e%d', 0:7), function(id) {
      input[[id]]
    }, simplify = FALSE))
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please provide an reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example .

Comment: I have provided a reproducible example.